# Does the law require the payment of interest for appearance bonds?

Tags: criminal-law, appearance

I see that Sec. 293. [8 U.S.C. 1363] Of the IMMIGRATION AND NATIONALITY ACT, it provides that the government pay 3 percent interest on bonds per year.

But in a criminal case in Texas, I can't find where the state must pay interest on appearance bonds in misdemenor cases there. Does it depend on the type of crime? Or is it normal for the state to not pay any interest while it uses your money while you await trial? In some cases 3 or 4 years.

Comment: Actually, the section you cite provides that the government pay an interest rate of *no more than* 3 percent per year: "...shall bear interest payable at a rate determined by the Secretary of the Treasury, except that in no case shall the interest rate exceed 3 per centum per annum."

Comment: Ah yes. I missed that. Ok, so no interest is paid probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8 USC 1363 is about immigration bonds. The Texan appearance bond you are talking about is not an immigration bond. Therefore 8 USC 1363 is not relevant.

It is not normal to pay interest on an appearance bond.